# Swig doesn't find path on compliation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

So I was trying out the API docs example from Swig.

```
var swig  = require('swig');

var tpl = swig.compileFile('tpl/index.html');
console.log(tpl({ pagename: 'awesome people', authors: ['Paul', 'Jim', 'Jane'] }));
```

But when I try to run `node index.js`, it gives me this error:

```
fs.js:427
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\tpl\index.html'
```

I'm pretty sure I've entered the path correctly. Is this because of Swig or me?

Comment: Well, is your template actually located at `C:\tpl\index.html`?  Probably not.

Comment: @Brad doesn't JavaScript believe that is a relative path?

Comment: JavaScript itself doesn't believe anything.  It seems that Swig doesn't know where that file is, and you will have to tell it.  Use `__dirname`.

Comment: sooo '__dirname/tpl/index.html'?

Comment: `__dirname + '/tpl/index.html'`